# Convergence of sequence $a_{n+1} = \int_0^{a_n}[1+\frac{\cos^{2n+1} t}{4}]dt$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> How to show that sequence
>   $$a_{n+1} = \int_0^{a_n}\left(1+\frac{\cos^{2n+1} t}{4}\right)\,dt$$
>   with $a_0 \in (0, 2\pi)$ is convergent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\tag1a_{n+1}-a_n = \int_0^{a_n}\frac{\cos^{2n+1}t}4\,\mathrm dt$$
so that (using $|\cos|\le 1$ and $\cos(\pi- x)=-\cos x $ etc.,
$$\begin{align}0\le a_{n+1}-a_n&\le \frac14a_n,& 0\le a_n\le\frac\pi2\\
0\le a_{n+1}-a_n&\le \frac14(\pi-a_n),& \frac\pi2\le a_n\le\pi\\
0\ge a_{n+1}-a_n&\ge - \frac14(a-\pi),& \pi\le a_n\le\frac32\pi\\
0\ge a_{n+1}-a_n&\ge -\frac14(2\pi-a_n),& \frac32\pi\le a_n\le2\pi.\\
\end{align}$$

In particular
$$ a_n\in[0,\pi]\implies a_n\le a_{n+1}\in[0,\pi]$$
$$ a_n\in[\pi,2\pi]\implies a_n\ge a_{n+1}\in[\pi,2\pi]$$
At any rate, $\{a_n\}_n$ is bounded and monotonic, hence convergent.

---

**Remark:** We see from the above that the slightly "wilder" recursion without the denominator $4$ leads to the same convergence result. In fact, even
$$ a_{n+1}=\int_0^{a_n}\left(1+q\cos^{2n+1}t\right)\,\mathrm dt$$
with $0<q<2$ and $a_0\in(0,2\pi)$ gives us convergence (though the limit may be $>2\pi$).